# Angular 2: Strategy for storing config settings

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am using angular CLI to create angular2 project. I am using a json file to store some configurable settings like api endpoint etc
CLI bundles all files so json file is not deployed separately in dist folder. This is a problem since there is no way to change these settings once deployed.
What's the strategy normally used to store such settings in angualr apps which can be edited without re-deployment?
Something similar to web.config or app.config.

Comment: what about link a json file in cdn?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi each customer will have a it's own json and why deploy to cdn when config file is already a part of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Have a folder `config` that have all your runtime environments configs this folder needs to be added in to `"assets"` array of `.angular-cli.config.`

Than you need to create a class that will represent your application settings, you can call that `AppSettings`.

Then modify your `main.ts` to have something like that:

```
fetch(configUrl, { method: 'get' })
.then((response) => {
  response.json()
    .then((data: any) => {
      if (environment.production) {
        enableProdMode();
      };
      platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: AppSettings, useValue: new AppSettings(data.config) }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    });
});
```

`configUrl` will contain your config file url e.g `/config/dev.json`
This way config will be fetched with `fetch API` and on app bootstrap your `AppSettings` will be automatically created.

You have to inject the `AppSettings` anywhere you wanna use that.

For more details checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46818439/angular-4-create-assets-files-per-environment/46859191#46859191)

Answer (score 0):

Adding file entry to assets in angular-cli.json will copy it as is to dist folder.

`"assets": [
        "assets",
        "fav.ico",
        "settings.json"
      ]`