# Angular 4 create assets / files per environment?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

We use environment variables within our angular app to read settings etc but is there a way to generate assets/files on build?

Basically we'd like to create an 'auth/settings.js' file in the assets folder containing client id's and apiUrl's unique to each environment. These will be used in the index.html (so outside of the angular app bootstrap )

e.g. the values in the environment.ts exported into a js / json file output to the assets folder so they can be read in index.html

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
title: 'default',
clientId: 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx',
clientUrl: 'https://localhost:4200/app',
apiUrl: 'https://localhost/api'

};
```

I have read that you can use mulitapps:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

This may work but looks like a lot of copy and pasting and we'll have quite a few versions of the build - I'm not sure if you can declare the common settings once and just extend the extra app settings (inheritance)?

Thanks

Comment: The question is to broad I believe but anyway have you looked into this https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter , using it I was able to do 2 different projects, each project got 4 different environments, with single code base, so using webpack and with my version was reading JSON config file that I provide using EVN variable.

Comment: Angular cli by default gives you development and production environment files that you can use. To store information like that. You can also define a proxy file to help with using various end points . You can pass the proxy file as a parameter to ng serve.

Comment: @JamesQuick seems like you talking about https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md but that it not the point and also you are not running `ng serve` on production.

Comment: @Kuncevic I certainly might be missing something. Your environment variables are picked up during the build process (either development or prod). So, if the question is how to have different sets of variables for dev and prod (which is my interpretation based on the example above, then that would solve the problem. The was just kind of an added thought.  I know you don't call ng serve in production :) Either way, if my understanding of the question is off, I'd be happy to have more clarification

Comment: Hi guys, yeah the point was we needed to have environment specific javascript files to use outside of angular (or before it bootstraps) in the index.html, this meant the environment.ts files didn't help us. In the end we used a build step in azure to replace the contents of our 'auth.js' with the environment specific versions

Comment: @MichaelHarper just updated the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we are doing in our case is actually having an `config.json` and `config.[env-name].json` files in `app/config` folder that configured in [project assets](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md). The `config.json` file is getting fetched before angular bootstrap using browser [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

On our build server we are just replacing the content of `config.json` with`config.staging.json` or `config.prod.json` based on environment build. Also we have `AppSettings` class that gets created on bootstrap. Here is how it is looks like:

```
fetch(configUrl, { method: 'get' })
.then((response) => {
  response.json()
    .then((data: any) => {
      if (environment.production) {
        enableProdMode();
      };
      platformBrowserDynamic([{ provide: AppSettings, useValue: new AppSettings(data.config) }]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**: 
If you need to stick some values based on your env in to `index.html` you might need to consider doing that on your build server. You can rather `string replace` the values or you can have `index.[env-name].thml` files so you just overwrite the `index.html` based on environment build.

Also check out this issues
 - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7506
 - https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855

Comment: Hi Kuncevic - this is what we ended up doing :)